# InternetDomainName and publicsuffix list

Tags: java, classpath, guava

Which version of public suffix list(https://publicsuffix.org/)  does Guava 21 InternetDomainName API use?

Parsing `keyupgrade.spaceforupdate.download` results in

```
scala> InternetDomainName.from("keyupgrade.spaceforupdate.download").topPrivateDomain
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not under a public suffix: keyupgrade.spaceforupdate.download
  at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
  at com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName.topPrivateDomain(InternetDomainName.java:445)
  ... 50 elided
```

But .download is a valid public suffix as per https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat.
I am thinking Guava 21 is using an older version of publicsuffix list. Is there a way to update it? Thanks!

Comment: The actual matching happens in the class [`PublicSuffixPatterns`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/thirdparty/publicsuffix/PublicSuffixPatterns.java), which is auto-generated, according to the comment at the top. Haven't been able to determine what process is being used, though. Perhaps ask the github-committer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This conversation was happening in parallel on the guava mailing list and here; I will consolidate it here. In the most recent reply on the mailing list, Neera responded to my request for example code with the following:

> I am trying to parse "keyupgrade.spaceforupdate.download" where
>   .download is a valid TLD as per the latest mozilla  public suffix
>   list, but Guava fails to parse it.
>
> scala>
>   InternetDomainName.from("keyupgrade.spaceforupdate.download").topPrivateDomain
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not under a public suffix:
>   keyupgrade.spaceforupdate.download   at
>   com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:176)
>   at
>   com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName.topPrivateDomain(InternetDomainName.java:445)
>   ... 50 elided

I'm wondering if this might be a Scala-specific issue. As I mentioned, 'download' has been in the PSL for a long time (since 2014-11-20 according to the PSL itself), and it's in the local copies of the PSL used to build Guava for years before version 21 was built. Note that I tested this in Java against our head version, and got the expected output, "spaceforupdate.download":

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    InternetDomainName top = 
        InternetDomainName.from("keyupgrade.spaceforupdate.download").topPrivateDomain();

    System.out.println(top);
  }
```

Do tests with "obvious" suffixes work? E.g., the top private domain of "www.google.com" should be "google.com". Please try that, and also, if possible, try a test in Java rather than Scala. I'll look forward to hearing how those tests go.

Comment: I upgraded to use Guava22, now parsing of rare TLD's such as .download works as expected. Thanks for your help. In future, will Guava have a way to download and update the psl file
 (https://publicsuffix.org/list/public_suffix_list.dat)? It will be a very useful features.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that! I'd like to provide a way to rebuild guava with the latest PSL, but it's a tricky thing to do right. Rest assured it's on my radar.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure you have a [Guava v14 jar](https://github.com/google/guava/releases/tag/v14.0) on your classpath, possibly [in addition to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Classloader#JAR_hell) the v21 jar you think you're using. It was released in 2013, before `.download` was apparently added as a TLD.

Looking at your stack trace, it indicates the exception was thrown from line 176 of `Preconditions.java`, but in [v21](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v21.0/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java#L176) that line is just a `*/`. Stepping backwards it's not until [v17](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v17.0/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java#L176) that the line number makes any sense.

Same problem with `InternetDomainName` - compare [v21](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v21.0/guava/src/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.java#L441) vs. [v14](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v14.0/guava/src/com/google/common/net/InternetDomainName.java#L445) (`Preconditions` also lines up in [v14](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/v14.0/guava/src/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.java#L176)).

So take a closer look at your classpath, I think that's your problem.

---

**Edit**: Confirmed this works in v21 with Scala:

```
$ scala -cp guava-21.0.jar
Welcome to Scala 2.11.11 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> import com.google.common.net._
import com.google.common.net._

scala> InternetDomainName.from("keyupgrade.spaceforupdate.download").topPrivateDomain
res0: com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName = spaceforupdate.download
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the principle maintainer of InternetDomainName. Sorry you're having problems with it.

It appears that the version of the PSL incorporated into Guava 21 was obtained from Mozilla on 2016-11-30. Unfortunately, there's no straightforward way to update it yourself.

That being said, I just looked back through older versions of the PSL, and "download" has been in there for a long time, well before the version used in Guava 21. Would you mind posting some working example code that demonstrates the problem you're seeing?

Comment: This conversation was happening in parallel on the guava mailing list and here; I will consolidate it here. In the most recent reply on the mailing list, Neera responded to my request for example code with the following:

Comment: Thanks Catherine! In my deployment, I think Spark is loading Guava 19, I will update the dependencies and see if I can load Guava 21.