# Extract domain from URLs using scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, guava, url-parsing

I am trying to extract domains from URLs.

Input:

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    val b = Seq(
        ("subdomain.example.com/test.php"),
        ("example.com"),
        ("example.buzz"),
        ("test.example.buzz"),
        ("subdomain.example.co.uk"),
    ).toDF("raw_url")
    var c = b.withColumn("host", callUDF("parse_url", $"raw_url", lit("HOST"))).show()
```

Expected results:

```
    +--------------------------------+---------------+
    | raw_url                        | host          |
    +--------------------------------+---------------+
    | subdomain.example.com/test.php | example.com   |
    | example.com                    | example.com   | 
    | example.buzz                   | example.buzz  |
    | test.example.buzz              | example.buzz  |
    | subdomain.example.co.uk        | example.co.uk |
    +------------------------------- +---------------+
```

Any advice much appreciated.

EDIT: based on the tip from @AlexOtt I have got a few steps closer.

```
    import com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    val b = Seq(
        ("subdomain.example.com/test.php"),
        ("example.com"),
        ("example.buzz"),
        ("test.example.buzz"),
        ("subdomain.example.co.uk"),
    ).toDF("raw_url")
    var c = b.withColumn("host", callUDF("InternetDomainName.from", $"raw_url", topPrivateDomain)).show()
```

However, I clearly have not implemented it correctly with withColumn. Here is the error:

> error: not found: value topPrivateDomain
> var c = b.withColumn("host", callUDF("InternetDomainName.from", $"raw_url", topPrivateDomain)).show()

EDIT 2:

Got some good pointers from @sarveshseri and after cleaning up some syntax errors, the following code is able to remove the subdomains from most of the URLs.

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    import com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName
    import java.net.URL

    val b = Seq(
       ("subdomain.example.com/test.php"),
       ("example.com"),
       //("example.buzz"),
       //("test.example.buzz"),
       ("subdomain.example.co.uk"),
       ).toDF("raw_url")

    val hostExtractUdf = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf { 
        (urlString: String) =>
        val url = new URL("https://" + urlString)
        val host = url.getHost
        InternetDomainName.from(host).topPrivateDomain().name()
    }

    var c = b.select("raw_url").withColumn("HOST", 
       hostExtractUdf(col("raw_url")))
        .show(false)
```

However, it still does not work as expected. Newer suffixes like `.buzz` and `.site` and `.today` cause the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not under a public suffix: example.buzz
```

Comment: you need to wrap some library that supports lookup via public suffix list: https://publicsuffix.org/ - the rules are quite complicated

Comment: Thanks for the tip @AlexOtt, that has somewhat helped. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046265/internetdomainname-and-publicsuffix-list. However, I'm still stuck on how to apply InternetDomainName.from().topPrivateDomain to withColumn

Answer (score 3):

First you will need to add `guava` to dependencies in `build.sbt`.

```scala
libraryDependencies += "com.google.guava" % "guava" % "31.0.1-jre"
```

Now you can extract the host as follows,

```scala
import com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName
import org.apache.sedona.core.serde.SedonaKryoRegistrator
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import java.net.URL

import spark.implicits._

val hostExtractUdf = org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf { (urlString: String) =>
  val url = new URL("https://" + urlString)
  val host = url.getHost
  InternetDomainName.from(host).topPrivateDomain().toString
}

val b = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("a.b.com/c.php"),
  ("a.b.site/c.php"),
  ("a.b.buzz/c.php"),
  ("a.b.today/c.php"),
  ("b.com"),
  ("b.site"),
  ("b.buzz"),
  ("b.today"),
  ("a.b.buzz"),
  ("a.b.co.uk"),
  ("a.b.site")
)).toDF("raw_url")

val c = b.withColumn("HOST", hostExtractUdf(col("raw_url")))

c.show()
```

`c.show` output

```
+---------------+-------+
|        raw_url|   HOST|
+---------------+-------+
|  a.b.com/c.php|  b.com|
| a.b.site/c.php| b.site|
| a.b.buzz/c.php| b.buzz|
|a.b.today/c.php|b.today|
|          b.com|  b.com|
|         b.site| b.site|
|         b.buzz| b.buzz|
|        b.today|b.today|
|       a.b.buzz| b.buzz|
|      a.b.co.uk|b.co.uk|
|       a.b.site| b.site|
+---------------+-------+
```

Comment: Is there any way to avoid using sbt?

Comment: You can use any other build tool like maven, gradle, pants, bazel etc. to build your peoject.

Comment: Good to know. Up until now, I have been using `:load` from spark-shell.

Comment: I cleaned up some syntax errors and got your code (mostly) working. However its unable to handle newer suffixes like `.buzz` and `.today` and `.site`.

Comment: Yes, I had only added the missing pieces in the code and it was not complete code. FIxed that. What do you mean by "unable to habdle `.buzz`, `'today` and `.site`" ? You can see in the code that it handles these without issue.

Comment: I mean that when I load the script into spark-shell, I get an error like `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not under a public suffix: example.buzz`. I think the  issue is due to Spark dependency on older version of Guava. Once I figure out how to `add guava to dependencies in build.sbt` I should be able to verify if this works.

Comment: I have tested this to work with `Guava 28 +`. Not sure about earlier versions.

Comment: I was able to get it working using `guava-31.0.1-jre.jar` without using SBT. Thank you for all your help with this!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use regex with Spark `regexp_extract` and `regexp_replace` built-in functions. Here's an example:

```scala
val c = b.withColumn(
  "HOST",
  regexp_extract(col("raw_url"), raw"^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www.)?([^:\/\n?]+)", 1)
).withColumn(
  "sub_domain",
  regexp_extract(col("HOST"), raw"(.*?)\.(?=[^\/]*\..{2,5})/?.*", 1)
).withColumn(
  "HOST",
  expr("trim(LEADING '.' FROM regexp_replace(HOST, sub_domain, ''))")
).drop("sub_domain")

c.show(false)
//+-----------------------------------+-------------+
//|raw_url                            |HOST         |
//+-----------------------------------+-------------+
//|subdomain.example.com/test.php     |example.com  |
//|example.com                        |example.com  |
//|example.buzz                       |example.buzz |
//|test.example.buzz                  |example.buzz |
//|https://www.subdomain.example.co.uk|example.co.uk|
//|subdomain.domain.buzz              |domain.buzz  |
//|dev.example.today                  |example.today|
//+-----------------------------------+-------------+
```

The first one extracts the the full host name from the URL (including the subdomain). Then, using the regex taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10526727/1386551), we search for the subdomain and replace it with blank.

Didn't test it for all possible cases but it works fine for the given examples in your question.

Comment: Although, I personally don't like the this self written regex appraoch for various reasons and will suggest to avoid such things in production code, you still have my upvote for the effort. Firstly, It is be very hard to correctly create. Second it will be very hard to maintain the ragex. Third, Guava is already doing this for you. The Guava implementation not only is maintained to follow the latest domain name specification, it also keeps track of all the ICANN public domains.